# Too many curl request for Apple Push Notifications

Tags: php, curl, apple-push-notifications

I am using this function to send push notifications

```
function SendPush($token,$message,$badge,$eventid) {

    $device_token   = $token;
    $pem_file       = '../pushcert.pem';
    $pem_secret     = 'pass';
    $apns_topic     = 'com.topic';


    $sample_alert = '{"aps":{"alert":"'. $message .'","sound":"default","badge":'. $badge .'}, "type":"attend", "eventID":"'.$eventid.'"}';
    $url = "https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/$device_token";

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sample_alert);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("apns-topic: $apns_topic"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pem_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $pem_secret);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $sonuc = json_decode($response,true);

    if ($sonuc['reason'] == "BadDeviceToken" || $sonuc['reason'] == "Unregistered" ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

It is working good. I can also detect the invalid tokens.

My problem is when I need to send over 1000 push notifications It takes too much time.

Is there a way to keep curl connection alive and send notifications faster without getting blocked by apple servers?

Comment: You could use a "connection pool". Guzzle (which is awesome whenever you need to do cURL-y stuff) has a built-in system for this: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html (see the section saying "You can use the GuzzleHttp\Pool object when you have an indeterminate amount of requests you wish to send.")

Answer (score 3):

For that, you have to put notification code in the background.

You can refer this URL: https://coderexample.com/how-to-run-a-php-script-in-background/

So, Your code will execute in 1 second and your notification will send from a background so, you do not wait for response till notification will be done.

**OR**

You can use Third party Notification tools

**FCM:**

> https://gist.github.com/rolinger/d6500d65128db95f004041c2b636753a

**OneSignal:**

> https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference

It will manage themselves only.

Comment: How can I get the result of curl after execute it in the background*

Comment: ignore_user_abort(true);
usleep(500000);    // wait 500ms
// do stuff

Answer (score 1):

PHP curl library should reuse HTTP connections by default, you only need to reuse curl handle.
So, solution is to do **$ch = curl_init($url);** once, outside of this method, and then add $ch as an argument to SendPush() in your loop where you process/send notifications.

This way, your HTTP connection will be persistent and lots of connection establishment time will be saved. At no cost and additional complexity, you get queuing effect.

Comment: Cannot do that because URL is changing in each function call so I need to reinit the curl

Comment: As long as HOST part of URL is not changed - yes you can.

Answer (score -1):

there is curl multi

```
<?php
//$message should be an array with the details
function SendPush($messages) {
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$ch = array();
foreach($messages as $key=>$mess)
{
    $device_token   = $mess['token'];
    $pem_file       = '../pushcert.pem';
    $pem_secret     = 'pass';
    $apns_topic     = 'com.topic';
    $sample_alert = '{"aps":{"alert":"'. $mess['message'] .'","sound":"default","badge":'. $mess['badge'] .'}, "type":"attend", "eventID":"'.$mess['eventid'].'"}';
    $url = "https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/$device_token";
    $ch[$key]=curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sample_alert);
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
    curl_setopt($ch[$key],CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("apns-topic: $apns_topic"));
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pem_file);
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $pem_secret);
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch[$key]);

}
$running = null;
do {
  curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while ($running);

$sonuc = json_decode($response,true);
foreach($ch as $curl)
{
    $response = curl_multi_getcontent($curl);
    if ($sonuc['reason'] == "BadDeviceToken" || $sonuc['reason'] == "Unregistered" ) {
        //return false;
        //handle the bad device
    } else {
        //return true;
        //device ok
    }
}
}
```

Comment: warning, `$mess['message']`,`$mess['badge']`, and `$mess['eventid']`  is not being properly json encoded here.

Comment: dude pass the items passed to the original function as an array to this function. one item of the array for each push notification. I think that should be obvious.